# How can i avoid the first and last Item in the dropdown at the time of Saving?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a  country dropdownlist. The first value is " Select a Country" and after that i have several country names. The last value in the ddl is "Other" to add a country that is not in the ddl....

So, here the first value "Select a Country" and the last value "Other" should not be saved but can be selected from the dropdownlist...

can you please help!!

Thank you!!

Comment: Please provide a code sample and a right-up of what you tried.

Comment: How about matching the strings exactly "Select a Country" and "Other" Or you can set their values to -1 or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the below code like

```
 foreach (ListItem l1 in DropDownList1.Items)
    { 
    if(l1.Text!="Select a Country" &&l1.Text!="Other")
    {
        //Write the code of insert
    }
    }
```

**Note:**
l1.Text comparision which is used in "if" condition must be same as dropdown list item text("Select a Country" Which is case sensitive also)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (need to import `System.Linq`):

```
var items = ddl.Items.Cast<ListItem>();
var itemCount = items.Count();
var itemsWithoutFirstAndLast = items.Skip(1).Take(itemCount-2);
```